# Magento 2 SimpleXMLElement (array to XML stream conversion error)

Tags: magento2, xml

```
$test_array = array (
                    'bla' => 'blub',
                    'foo' => 'bar',
                    'another_array' => array (
                        'stack' => 'overflow',
                    ),
                );
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<root/>');
array_walk_recursive($test_array, array ($xml, 'addChild'));
$xmldata =$xml->asXML();
```

But its showing

> fatal error:SimpleXMLElement' not found.

I used same thing in Magento 1.9 and it worked that time.

Answer (score 2):

Try using a forward slash before the `SimpleXMLElement` like

```
$xml = new \SimpleXMLElement('<root/>');
```

or you can try

```
function arrayToXml($array, $rootElement = null, $xml = null) {
  $_xml = $xml;

  if ($_xml === null) {
    $_xml = new SimpleXMLElement($rootElement !== null ? $rootElement : '<root/>');
  }

  foreach ($array as $k => $v) {
    if (is_array($v)) { //nested array
      arrayToXml($v, $k, $_xml->addChild($k));
    } else {
      $_xml->addChild($k, $v);
    }
  }

  return $_xml->asXML();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**FIX:**
I believe you need to alias 'SimpleXMLElement' before using it.
Just write it after namespace :  `Use SimpleXMLElement` and it should work.

**Magento Solution:**
I would like to mention that magento has already extended Simplexml which you can use. Check the class

```
Magento\Framework\Simplexml\Element
```

This class Extends SimpleXML to add valuable functionality to \SimpleXMLElement. Also make sure to use it by dependency in your custom class.